Should we delete some off-topic questions?
There's been a spate of completely off-topic question lately.  For those with access to moderator tools, you can see a list there.  For others, see for example,

java book comparison
how to weigh the subsets sequences of time series
time series analysis
How to get the degrees of a line? (linear regression)

As far as I can tell, continuing to have these on the site serves no long-lasting purpose, so perhaps we should move to get rid of them completely.  Anyone disagree?  I realize we may not have enough users with delete privileges, so perhaps a moderator can step in to delete them if there is come consensus from the community?
Feel free to suggest more questions for deletion in answers, or to argue for keeping any of those I've suggested.

Good point. I have considered deleting instead of closing, but I wasn't sure if closed questions provide a record of what is off topic (OT). Future questioners can see what is OT and read comments to improve their question. 
But a lot of closed questions do make the site appear less mature. Maybe that's OK in beta?
Good question. I am interested to see what the rest of the group thinks.

I do love the degrees of a line question. I would hate to see it go.

As richardh points out, closed questions do provide a record of what is OT. But to what end?Most people that post off-topic questions don't bother reading FAQs nor researching old questions. I believe the main justification for keeping closed questions on the quant.SE is when they've somehow originated good and useful answers.
